# How to hide the Windows taskbar behind a PyQt window?

Tags: windows, pyqt

I'm looking for a way to display my PyQt window on top of the windows taskbar to hide the clock under it. Is there a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Did the trick.